# Who are the "alternate" bosses?

Tags: killing-floor-2

I have seen tweets from Killing Floor 2 and interviews in which they said they are hidden secret bosses in Killing Floor 2. Aside from the Patriarch, who are these bosses? I've been playing the beta extensively the past day and haven't yet seen any boss besides from the Patriarch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now Patriarch and Hans Volter are the only bosses in the game, with (as far as I have seen) no announcements of new ones being planned

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen, Hans Volter is currently the only boss in the game.

The Patriarch hasn't even been revealed yet (though it has been confirmed).

Doesn't mean there aren't secrets to be found, though :D

Answer (score 0):

It's too soon to tell, the game is still in beta phase, perhaps there will be announcements on this anytime soon.